# Delay in exoplayer on orientaion change

Tags: android, delay, android-orientation, exoplayer

The issue is that there is a delay when I try to change the orientation of the player.  There is a lag of some 2 or 3 seconds before the video resumes. Every thing else works just fine except for the orientation change.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String STATE_RESUME_WINDOW = "resumeWindow";
    private final String STATE_RESUME_POSITION = "resumePosition";
    private final String STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN = "playerFullscreen";
    private SimpleExoPlayerView mExoPlayerView;
    private MediaSource mVideoSource;
    private boolean mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
    private FrameLayout mFullScreenButton;
    private ImageView mFullScreenIcon;
    private Dialog mFullScreenDialog;

    private int mResumeWindow;
    private long mResumePosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mResumeWindow = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW);
            mResumePosition = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION);
            mExoPlayerFullscreen = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN);
        }
     }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW, mResumeWindow);
        outState.putLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION, mResumePosition);
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN, mExoPlayerFullscreen);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     }

    private void initFullscreenDialog() {

        mFullScreenDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (mExoPlayerFullscreen)
                    closeFullscreenDialog();
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        };
    }

    private void openFullscreenDialog() {

        ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
        mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_shrink));
        mExoPlayerFullscreen = true;
        mFullScreenDialog.show();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    private void closeFullscreenDialog() {

        ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_media_frame)).addView(mExoPlayerView);
        mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
        mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
        mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_expand));
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    private void initFullscreenButton() {

        PlaybackControlView controlView = mExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);
        mFullScreenIcon = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
        mFullScreenButton = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button);
        mFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mExoPlayerFullscreen)
                    openFullscreenDialog();
                else
                    closeFullscreenDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initExoPlayer() {

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),trackSelector, loadControl);
        mExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        boolean haveResumePosition = mResumeWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;

        if (haveResumePosition) {
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().seekTo(mResumeWindow, mResumePosition);
        }

        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().prepare(mVideoSource);
        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        if (mExoPlayerView == null) {

            mExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exoplayer);
            initFullscreenDialog();
            initFullscreenButton();

            String streamUrl = "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8";
            String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName);
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, null,
            DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
            DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
            DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(MainActivity.this, null,httpDataSourceFactory);
            Uri daUri = Uri.parse(streamUrl);
            mVideoSource = new HlsMediaSource(daUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        }

        initExoPlayer();

        if (mExoPlayerFullscreen) {
            ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
            mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,
            R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_shrink));
            mFullScreenDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();

        if (mExoPlayerView != null && mExoPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
            mResumeWindow = mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getCurrentWindowIndex();
            mResumePosition = Math.max(0, mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getContentPosition());
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().release();
        }

        if (mFullScreenDialog != null)
            mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your activity is destroyed and recreated onOrientation change. You can handle the orientation change yourself to avoid the player to be destroyed. My guess is the delay is because the player needs to wait for the first keyframe until it can start rendering the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [handling configuration changes yourself](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) - as @marcbaechinger mentions above.

The necessary piece is here:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

The most important part is:

> Remember: When you declare your activity to handle a configuration change, you are responsible for resetting any elements for which you provide alternatives. If you declare your activity to handle the orientation change and have images that should change between landscape and portrait, you must re-assign each resource to each element during onConfigurationChanged().

But if you don't have any landscape specific layout files or images, then you'll likely be okay.

We had to write our own full screen logic for rotation, but that's simple enough considering Android gives you the configuration change event.

And to tack on a little extra validity to this approach, it's recommended by Google via the [Youtube player documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) (specifically in regards to fullscreen):

> To achieve this for an activity that supports portrait, you need to specify that your activity handles some configuration changes on its own in your application's manifest, including orientation, keyboardHidden and screenSize.

Comment: God bless you for this answer.